# How do I stop server mounted USB drives showing a dialogue on thin clients

Tags: 10.04, ltsp

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 64bit Desktop on my server with LTSP5.2 and 10 workstations.

Everytime I put a CD or USB disk into the server it shows up with an error on all the workstations saying
'Unable to Mount '

Is there a way to stop these messages from showing on thin clients?

Comment: Consider a system where more than one users are logged in, using switch user facility. This is similar to the issue 'Not Authorized' warning you see, when user A plugs in USB and later switches to user B, already logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Open `gconf-editor` from terminal.

Then untick `/apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount_open` key.

This disables automatic opening of a folder for automounted media

This seems to be a per user setting.

Comment: I also had to untick /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the following links,

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9338967#post9338967

or

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cdrom-detect/+bug/574468  and in this link search for the answer by

Comment: These links seem to talk about issues with installation, I don't have that problem. I have a fully working system. When I put a CD or USB drive into the server all the clients see an error message on their thin clients.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Since, as @map7 said, these links (which basically comprise the whole answer, and the second one doesn't seem to work anymore) don't address OP's situation, this should probably be considered not to address the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you enabled the LTSP automount feature.

Have a look at this [information page on LTSP](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ltsp/index.php?title=Ltsp_LocalMedia) under the title "autofs"

Comment: Please add more details; how to get rid of the dialogue.